# solr suggester not working with shard for multiple core

Tags: solr

I'm trying to use the suggest component (solr 4.6) with multiple cores. I have added a search component and a request handler in my solrconfig. That works fine for 1 core but querying my solr instance with the shards parameter does not work.

But did you mean' (spell check ) is working fine with multiple cores using shard.

Here is the configuration part of solrconfig file :

```
    <searchComponent class="solr.SpellCheckComponent" name="suggest">
    <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">suggestDictionary</str>
      <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
      <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.fst.FSTLookupFactory</str>
      <str name="field">suggest</str>
      <float name="threshold">0.0005</float>
      <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
    </lst>
  </searchComponent>
  <requestHandler name="/suggest" class="org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">none</str>
      <str name="wt">xml</str>
      <str name="indent">false</str>
      <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">suggestDictionary</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.count">5</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collate">false</str>
      <str name="qt">/suggest</str>
      <str name="shards.qt">/suggest</str>
     <str name="shards">localhost:8080/cores/core1,localhost:8080/cores/core2</str>
      <bool name="distrib">false</bool>
    </lst>
    <arr name="components">
      <str>suggest</str>
    </arr>
       <shardHandlerFactory class="HttpShardHandlerFactory">
      <int name="socketTimeOut">1000</int>
      <int name="connTimeOut">5000</int>
    </shardHandlerFactory>
  </requestHandler>
```

Comment: Have you got the question on your answer. I am facing the same problem. Need your help?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me..

You can get the **suggestions** using this **RestURL**

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/demo/spell?q=howoo&wt=json&indent=true&qt=spell&shards.qt=/spell&shards=localhost:8983/solr/demo_shard2_replica1,localhost:8983/solr/demo_shard1_replica2
```

**OR** Simply use this :

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/demo/spell?q=hoo&wt=json&indent=true&shards.qt=/spell
```

**shards.qt=/spell** : Need to add that allows **suggestion** on **shards**

Here, you have **make changes** and apply for things which requires.

```
Collection = demo
Shards = demo_shard2_replica1, demo_shard1_replica2
```

Replace **collection** and **shards** names with **your names of collection and shards**.